# ERROR: function make_standard_name(unknown) does not exist while installing OSM-nominatim API

Tags: centos, postgresql

I am installing nominatim on my own server using the guidence of http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation...

But I am facing problem while adding country phrases / codes to my pgsql DB.
I am doing this with following command as given in above link:

```
psql -d nominatim -f specialphrases_countries.sql
```

But, I am getting following error:

```
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:1: ERROR:  function make_standard_name(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select getorcreate_country(make_standard_name('uk'), 'gb');
                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:2: ERROR:  function make_standard_name(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select getorcreate_country(make_standard_name('united states...
                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:3: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e_standard_name(country_code), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:4: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ...try_name.name,ARRAY['name'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:5: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:af'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:6: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:ar'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:7: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:br'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:8: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:ca'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:9: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:cs'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:10: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:de'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:11: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:en'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:12: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:es'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:13: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:et'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:14: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:eu'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:15: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:fa'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:16: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:fi'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:17: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:fr'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:18: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:gl'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:19: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:hr'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:20: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:hu'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:21: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:ia'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:22: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:is'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:23: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:it'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:24: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:ja'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:25: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:mk'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:26: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:nl'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:27: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:no'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:28: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:pl'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:29: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:ps'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:30: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:pt'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:31: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:ru'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:32: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:sk'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:33: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:sv'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:34: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:uk'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
psql:specialphrases_countries.sql:35: ERROR:  relation "country_name" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._name.name,ARRAY['name:vi'])), country_code) from country_na...
                                                             ^
```

I dont know what is "make_standard_name(unknown)", how to create it to solve "ERROR:  function make_standard_name(unknown) does not exist"...

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The function make_standard_name(text) is added to the database by the proceeding step in the install process: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Import_and_index_OSM_data

If this function is missing then either that step was missed or an error occurred during that step.  You will need to run it successfully before you can import the extra country name data.